# how to add checkbox(QCheckBox) in focus chain

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Actually, I am trying to develop a small application in Qt creator framework, in Dialog I have added some `QLineEdit` and `QCheckBox` and I have reimplemented `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)` where I have set that when I press Enter key, it will focus on next Available input but I want to set `QCheckBox` also to be added in next focus chain. below is my Code:

Qt Creator 5.12.0 on Mac os x Seirra

```
void Dialog::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *ev)
{
    if(ev->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || ev->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
    {
        this->focusNextPrevChild(true);
    }
}
```

How can I make when I enter it should focus on Checkbox, radio buttons and Push buttons also.

Comment: I see that with the QCheckBox there is no problem (I have tested it on Linux) so maybe the error is caused by another part of your code so you need to provide an MCVE

Comment: I have solved the problem.

Comment: Solution: in Qt Designer i set FocusPolicy to Solid.